# how does fabric execute commands?

Tags: ssh, fabric, tty

i am wondering how does fabric execute commands.

Let's say I give him `env.user=User`, `env.host=HOST`. Then i ask him to `sudo('ls')`
Is that equivalent to me typing in a shell : `ssh User@host 'sudo(/bin/ls)'`
or it's more : `ssh User@host` in a first time, then `sudo ls` commande in a seconde time ?

I'm asking that because sometimes using a shell, if the TTY has a bad configuration (I am a bit blurry on this), `ssh User@Host 'sudo /bin/ls'`
return : `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`
but you can first log in with `ssh User@Host` then `sudo ls` and it works.

I don't know how to replicate the no tty error, but I know it can occurs. Would this block the sudo commande from Fabric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically how it works is:

- First a connection is established (equivalent as doing `ssh User@host`)
- Over this connection a command is executed as follows:

  ```
  sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  /bin/bash -l -c "your_command"
  ```

  You can also allow Fabric not to request a pty with either `pty=False` argument, `env.always_use_pty=False` or `--no-pty` commandline option.